# Two mpm_even_module in apache2.conf

Tags: apache2, apache-config

I happened to check the production box configuration and I noticed that there are two `mpm_worker_module` configurations. I would like to have only one reconciled configuration.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ThreadLimit         150
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          400
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadsPerChild     150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>


<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Both of these configuration are different. Apache doesn't give any error If I run this command 'apache2ctl configtest`. Looks like it is valid to have two configurations for same module. But I am pretty much sure that it takes only one configuration into consideration. 
I want to know what is the current configuration apache is using. I tried to run 'apache2ctl status' to status of the apache I got the following error.

```
'www-browser -dump http://localhost:80/server-status' failed.
Maybe you need to install a package providing www-browser or you
need to adjust the APACHE_LYNX variable in /etc/apache2/envvars
                                   Forbidden

   You don't have permission to access /server-status on this server.
```

I would like to know if there is any command to get the current `mpm_worker_module` configuration?
Is there any command which can tell me `MaxClients` value?

Comment: Go back and read those `IFModule` statements a bit closer.  Only one is active based on the MPM you've chosen.  You'll find the MPM by invoking `apachectl -V` and looking for the `Server MPM` line.  Most distros ship the prefork MPM by default.

Comment: @Charles This command tells you about the module being used. But it doesn't tell you the current configuration parameters' value. I want to check the current configuration parameters' value.

Comment: You can know this based on the MPM being used and reading the value in the configuration file.  Unfortunately Apache is *horrible* at being able to tell you current configuration variables.  You should focus on getting `/server-status` working.